# Integrating Google Maps with ASP.NET website

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-maps-api-3

Hi, yes I have battled with the Google Documentation, and no, I was not asking anybody to write an application for me FoC! I do quite a lot of SQL forum answering myself on MSDN, and get how the forums work, just probably asked the question quite badly. I appreciate you pointing this out, as hopefully it will lead to more chance of the question being answered. As mentioned, I was really just hoping that somebody could post some working samples of the things I was discussing with, that I could then tinker with. The code that I have so far is below, but is in a bit of a state. Passing in the parameters to the Javascript is not working and I can't figure out how to even start making it accept user interactions with the map as inputs. The sample my code is based on came from a forum thread as I found this much more helpful than the official Google documentation!

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
       <head> 
               <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/> 
               <title>Calculate Distance</title>
                <script type="text/javascript"    
                             src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

       </head>
       <body style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 13px; color: red;">
           <form runat="server">
                <div id="map" style="width: 400px; height: 300px;"></div>
                 <script type="text/javascript">
                     var startlocation = document.getElementById('Start').textcontent;
                     var endlocation = document.getElementById('End').textContent;
                     var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
                     var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
                     var myOptions = 
                         {      zoom:7,      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP    }     
                     var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
                     directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
                     var request = 
                         {        
                             origin:  startlocation,
                             destination: endlocation,
                             travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING  
                         }; 
                     directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) { 
                         if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) { 
                             // Display the distance:
                             document.getElementById('Distance').innerHTML += 
                                 response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value / 1609.344 + " miles";
                             directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
                         }
                     });

                 </script>
           <asp:Label ID="Distance" runat="server" Text="Distance: "></asp:Label>
           <asp:TextBox ID="Start" runat="server" Text="hedge end"></asp:TextBox>
           <asp:TextBox ID="End" runat="server" Text="fareham"></asp:TextBox>
               <asp:Button ID="CalcDistance" runat="server" Text="Button" />
            </form>
       </body>  

 </html>
```

I am new to javascript and pretty new to ASP.NET and I have been fiddling with this for days and can't get anywhere.

I want to integrate Google Maps into an ASP.NET page, so that the user can choose to either click 2 points on the map, or instead choose to insert one or both of the addresses into text boxes.

Once the two locations have either been entered or plotted on the map, I then need to return the shortest driving distance in miles to an ASP.NET control.

If somebody could help me out by posting a working sample of this or something similar, I would be really greatful.

Many thanks in advance for your help.

Pete

Comment: Have you looked at the [Google Maps API documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial)? This should help you build the basic map. Show us what you have tried so far and where you are struggling, and you will get help. Nobody here will build you the entire application from scratch.

Comment: +1 I didn't want to frustrate you, nor did I want to sound harsh in my comment. The original question was just too generic, without any code or concrete scenario. It is way better now and definitely deserves an answer.

Answer (score 1):

[Start with this tutorial.](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/291499/Google-Maps-API-V3-for-ASP-NET)

[Documentation is here.](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial)

[How to calculate distance is here.](http://briancray.com/posts/how-to-calculate-the-distance-between-two-addresses-with-javascript-and-google-maps-api/)

EDIT:

This is distance calculation example with Google Maps API v3 and ASP.NET.

Client code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/> 
    <title>Calculate Distance</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&v=3&libraries=geometry"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        #map{width:800px;height:500px}
    </style>

</head>

<body style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 13px; color: red;">
<form id="Form1" runat="server">

    <div id="map"></div>

    <input runat="server" type="hidden" id="DistanceValue" name="DistanceValue" />

    <script type="text/javascript">

        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(54.40708, 18.667485);
        var latlng2 = new google.maps.LatLng(54.40708, 18.667485);

        var myOptions =
            {
            zoom:4,
            center:latlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };

        var map= new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),myOptions);

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng,
            title: "Westerplatte - first battle of WW2 in Europe",
            clickable: true, 
            map: map
        });

        var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng2,
            title: "Westerplatte - first battle of WW2 in Europe",
            clickable: true,
            map: map
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function (event) {
            latlng2 = new google.maps.LatLng(event.latLng.lat(), event.latLng.lng());
            marker2.setMap(null);
            marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latlng2,
                title: "selected by user",
                clickable: true,
                map: map
            });

            var hidden = document.getElementById("DistanceValue");
            hidden.value = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(latlng, latlng2) / 1000;
        });

    </script>


    <asp:Button  ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Send distance" onclick="Button1_Click" />

    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>

</form>
</body>  

</html>
```

Server code:

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Request.Form["DistanceValue"] != null)
        {
            string myHiddenFiledValue = Request.Form["DistanceValue"].ToString();
            Label1.Text = myHiddenFiledValue.Split(',','.')[0] + " [km]";
        }
    }
```